# How can I use the full resolution of a Macbook Pro Retina 15"?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

It is supposed to be a 2880 x 1800 pixel display, but System Preferences won't let me set it higher than 1920 x 1200.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the pref pane?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences -> Display.
By default, it should have been at full resolution, but if not, then
Select manually the resolution to 2880x1800.

Comment: And how should the OP do that if all he/she can see is 1920x1200?

Comment: By default Retina Macbook Pro does not have full resolution. You can do that via 3rd party app. Use ChangeResolution, an applescript to run your Mac at full Retina resolution. Get it at http://pastebin.com/wyDJi51x